# Polymer paper-input mask

Tags: javascript, polymer, mask, web-component, paper-elements

I'm using Polymer (v1.4.0) for a project and I'd like to know if is there any way to add an input mask for the paper-input?

I've tried to use the [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) adding it directly to the paper-input's inputElement but then the binding and change event stopped working.

If that's not possible, do you know any other text input web component with mask support?

Thanks!
André

Answer (score 3):

You can use the gold-xxx-input elements as template how to build your custom masked input element https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/gold-cc-input

Comment: Yeah I was checking those components now. Do you know if there is already a web component with mask support? I couldn't find any in the https://customelements.io/ as well. Otherwise, I'll go for it, I just  don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No, haven't seen one yet with generic mask support.

Comment: Actually, `paper-input` does support masking (see my answer).

Comment: That's not what I understand masking is, but if it solves your problem ... :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Ok :) but isn't the concept of masking clarified in the link to [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)? I'm curious now... What's your definition of masking?

Comment: For example the gold-cc-input that has a mask where 4 groups of numbers have to be added or a date input like explained in jquery.inputmask where the mask defines how a date has to be entered, ...

Comment: Ok, I see. That's true.

Comment: These gold components do support masking but not custom as Günter Zöchbauer mentioned above. They only have CC, email, and phone but for me that covers my needs.

Comment: @ScottRomack I just suggested using the element as starting point for your custom mask. You can just copy the source and modify the mask-related code. The code looked simple enough back then when I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use `<paper-input>`'s [`allowedPattern`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-allowedPattern) with [`preventInvalidInput`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-preventInvalidInput). For example, this masks out non-numeric input:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.9.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-input label="enter an integer"
               prevent-invalid-input
               allowed-pattern="[\d]+"></paper-input>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pboard?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: This answer does not provide the same functionality that jquery.inputmask provides. While you can control what the user types, you can't automatically add characters to the text, like typing a phone number and having the dashes and spaces inserted for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with in polymer 2 and paper-input out of the box, no custom coding using a phone number as an example. A somewhat close approximation of the masked input without the super nice adding of the dashes(-) automagically.

paper-input-mask is something that is needed though.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.9.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>



  <paper-input

    auto-validate
    allowed-pattern="[0-9-]"
    pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}"
    prevent-invalid-input
    label="Mobile Phone"
    placeholder="___-___-___"

    id="phoneNumber"
    type="tel"
    disabled$=[[disabled]]
  >
  </paper-input>




</body>
```